# one row records

Tags: jquery, sql, database, postgresql

hellow i wanna create a table that shows you the schedular of your week
it didn'k work it put for each work of the day in another row but i wanted it in a single row

```
select distinct jour.date_jour,matiere.etudes,day_matiere.start_time,day_matiere.end_time
from day_matiere
    inner join jour on jour.id_jour=day_matiere.id_jour
    inner join matiere on matiere.id_matiere=day_matiere.id_matiere
    inner join class on class.id_class=day_matiere.id_class
    inner join fillere on fillere.id_fillere=day_matiere.id_fillere
    GROUP BY jour.date_jour,matiere.etudes,day_matiere.start_time,day_matiere.end_time
```

the result i get is this
[image]
but i want a result like this
(photoshoped)
[image]
i tried the group by or distinct but it didn't work i tried for 1week
i can provide more information

Comment: What if there are more than 2 rows? Will you need 3 more columns etudes/start_time/end_time in the results?

Comment: yeah as long it's shows the dates of that  day in one row ,

Comment: A query returns a fixed number of columns.

Comment: i want a query that gives me the all the [etudes] and [Start_time],[end_time] of that single day [date_jour ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have variable number of columns for each case.
What you can do is get a comma separated list of the concatenated values of the columns, with `string_agg()` all in 1 column:

```
select 
  j.date_jour,
  string_agg(m.etudes || ' ' || dm.start_time || ' ' || dm.end_time, ', ') col
from day_matiere dm
inner join jour j on j.id_jour = dm.id_jour
inner join matiere m on m.id_matiere = dm.id_matiere
inner join class c on c.id_class = dm.id_class
inner join fillere f on f.id_fillere = dm.id_fillere
group by j.date_jour
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir , can i change the col name?